# how to use the default typeface when failed to load custom typeface?

Tags: android, typeface

I'm trying to load custom typeface.

It's working okay in a new model phone, but making an error in old model when loading custom typeface.

I think old model phone doesn't support the custom typeface. I guess i need to make it alternative with default typeface.

So I tried "try and catch" for alternative way.

But it still make the same error.

Shall anybody see my code and provide any suggestions?
thank you.

```
face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/letter.ttf");
    face2 = Typeface.SANS_SERIF;

    try{
    noteET.setTypeface(face);
    }catch(Exception e){
        noteET.setTypeface(face2);
    }
```

In `Note.java`, it has custom `EditText` which contains backgound notepad lines.
I think because the custom font doesn't support it, the line height for drawing line can't be calculated.

Error Message is Below:

```
**10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

**10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero**

**10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159):     at myapp.secretdiary.second.Note$EditOnList.onDraw(Note.java:195)**

10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)

10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)

10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)

10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)

10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)

10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)

10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)

10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)

10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)

10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)

10-31 07:09:05.275: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5159):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
*********more************
```

`Note.Java:195` line source is below

```
public static class EditOnList extends EditText{  //Noepad Line Drawing

    public EditOnList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        int count = getLineCount();
        int height = this.getHeight();
        int line_height = this.getLineHeight();
        int size = height/line_height+1;  // line 195
        if (count<size)count=size;

        int y = 2;
        for(int i=1; i<count; i++){
            y += line_height;
            canvas.drawLine(0+60, y, this.getRight()-60, y, p);
        }
    }

}  // EditOnList
```

Comment: Twice you say you get the same error, but you never tell us _which_ error. Try again.

Comment: sorry, i add my error log and more code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your catch isn't necessary.
When the custom ttf can't be loaded and you caught this error so that your App doesn't crash the default Typeface is choosen automatically.

Comment: thank you for answer. it means it's not the prob of try catch. i need to inspect more for the error